# Passing data from model to controller

Tags: ios, swift, model-view-controller

I am wondering what would be the best practice when I want to pass data from model to controller.

**What I want to do**
I would like to update a label when the time changes.

CurrentTime.swift (Model)

```
var timer: Timer?
    var currentTime: String?

    init() {
        if timer == nil{
            timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(updateCurrentTime), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        }
    }

    @objc private func updateCurrentTime(){
        let df = DateFormatter()
        df.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
        df.timeZone = TimeZone.current
        let timezoneDate = df.string(from: Date())
        currentTime = timezoneDate
    }
```

ViewController.swift

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var timeLabel: UILabel!
    var currentTime = CurrentTime()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    }

    @IBAction func closeBtnWasPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: You can post a `Notification` or provide a way to register observer closures with your model. You should set up the date formatter as a lazy private property rather than creating it each time the timer fires. Dateformatters are relatively expensive to create.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1**

1- Add this var

```
weak var delegate: ViewController?
```

2- in `viewDidLoad` of the vc

```
currentTime.delegate = self
```

3-

```
let timezoneDate = df.string(from: Date())
currentTime = timezoneDate
delegate?.update(currentTime)
```

4- inside the vc

```
func update(_ data:String) {
  lbl.text = data
}
```

off course you can do

```
delegate?.lbl.text = currentTime
```

but above is MVC

**Option 2**

```
var ob:NSKeyValueObservation!
```

and in `viewDidLoad`

```
ob =  currentTime.observe(\CurrentTime.currentTime, options: .new) { cur, tex in
    timeLabel.text = tex
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should define a Dynamic class like this:

```
class Dynamic<T> {

    var bind: (T) -> Void = { _ in }

    var value: T? {
        didSet {
            bind(value!)
        }
    }

    init(_ v: T) {
        value = v
    }
}
```

In your model change definition of the currentTime  property like this:

```
var currentTime: Dynamic<String>
```

In your controller in viewDidLoad method add these codes:

```
yourModel.currentTime.bind = { [weak self] time in
  self?.timeLabel.text = time
}
```